# Configure Less with PhpStorm doesn't compile

Tags: less, phpstorm

I am trying to compile my `styles.less` to `styles.css`. My folder structure is following:

```
assets->less->styles.less
assets->css->styles.css
```

I believe my configurations are wrong. In PhpStorm I set less output path to refresh: `../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

I do have a `styles.css` file under the `less` file and it is compiling. 
So far I only know regular CSS so I'm not very familiar with Less yet.
Any help?

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot with your File Watcher. So far (huge chance, I can feel it) it sounds like you did not set it up properly (not entered all params correctly).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qA0f57u.png  folder strcture is little different i tryed to simplify things. Thanks for the quick answer by the way! @LazyOne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your File Watcher setup is incomplete.

Right now it will save the generated file next to the source... but you need it 2 folders up.

You did set up correctly in `Output paths to refresh` .. but that file tells IDE what file to check when file watcher is finished running. It is not where the generated file will be placed.

You need to alter your `Arguments` field.

- Currently you have ... `$FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` ...
- You need to adjust the path there -- it has to be ... `$FileName$ ../../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` ... -- because that's where you specify such path.

(leading and trailing "..." means other parameters that you have got there)

Comment: i tryed this approach but now it is genereting new file with a name of: "..\..\css\component_styles.css"

Comment: I had to use "/" instead of "\". Everythings working! thanks!

Comment: Well ... `\ ` are for Windows, and `/` are for Linux/MacOS. You have used `\` in "Output paths to refresh" field yourself -- I've just copied it over. Glad you found the reason quickly.

Comment: There are many answers around regardings this issue. But this one is easy and simply works ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should have changed the **Arguments** field accordingly;

Like:

```
Arguments: --no-color $FileName$ $ProjectFileDir$/themes/elisa/assets/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(less)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/themes/elisa/assets/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(less)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

[image]